# Ros and Anaconda on an OS X homebrew installI

Tags: ros, python, homebrew, osx, anaconda

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to get ROS to play nicely with my Anaconda python. I know the prevailing answer to this problem is. "Don't." but I need Anaconda for other elements of my workflow.

My main issue is this:

```
$ roswtf
Fatal Python error: PyThreadState_Get: no current thread
Abort trap: 6
```

which [seems to be the result of the wrong python being called](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15678153/homebrew-python-on-mac-os-x-10-8-fatal-python-error-pythreadstate-get-no-cu). What I'm not sure about is how ROS binaries know which python version to use. Does anyone have experience with this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/228105/ros-and-anaconda-on-an-os-x-homebrew-installi/) by [nckswt](https://answers.ros.org/users/3362/nckswt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 539 on 2016-03-03

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The version of python that gets called is the one on your PATH that matches the #! line in the script. There are several places however that the python interpreter is cached during the build and installation phases that might catch you up with a problem.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2017-08-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0